# Deploy NodeJs Express App on Windows and Linux Server

Tags: node.js

I am developing a small project which contains few applications:

- A node.js rest API
- A node.js app that use socket.io.
- A static app that server html js file to the client.

I am also using a MongoDb.

In few weeks, I'll have to deploy this app in production and I have some requirements that the app should be installed on windows and Linux server (Don't really know if it really matters).

I had a look at some tooling :

- [StrongLoop Process Manager](http://strong-pm.io/)
- [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)
- [Forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)

But cannot really find out if these tools are up to date or if there are better alternative in 2016 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are what seem to be the recommended ways that I've found:

Windows: [iis-node](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) (and [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0) is helpful to get that going). Also note you'll need IIS 8x to support websockets.

Linux: PM2 to manage the process, and nginx for proxy server. [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04) has helpful step-by-step for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. Should do the trick. We may be using iis-node because the app may be host on azure in the future